# Running Kubernetes Sample Controller

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to run the Kubernetes sample controller example by following the link https://github.com/kubernetes/sample-controller. I have the repo set up on an Ubuntu 18.04 system and was able to build the sample-controller package.
However, when I try to run the go package, I am getting some errors and am unable to debug the issue. Can someone please help me with this?

Here are the steps that I followed :

```
user@ubuntu-user:~$ go get k8s.io/sample-controller
user@ubuntu-user:~$ cd $GOPATH/src/k8s.io/sample-controller
```

Here's the error that I get on running the controller:

```
user@ubuntu-user:~/go/src/k8s.io/sample-controller$ ./sample-controller -kubeconfig=$HOME/.kube/config
E0426 15:05:57.721696   31517 reflector.go:125] k8s.io/sample-controller/pkg/generated/informers/externalversions/factory.go:117: Failed to list *v1alpha1.Foo: the server could not find the requested resource (get foos.samplecontroller.k8s.io)
```

Kubectl Version :

````
user@ubuntu-user:~$ kubectl version 
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1", GitCommit:"b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-08T17:11:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1", GitCommit:"b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-08T17:02:58Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"```
````

Comment: Hello @LM10, could you provide more information? What OS you are using, any cloud provider, which version of K8s?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04(local desktop, no Cloud Provider)
kubectl version : 
```Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1", GitCommit:"b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-08T17:11:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1", GitCommit:"b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-08T17:02:58Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it refers to code on another site, that could change in the future, making the question useless at that point. SO prefers questions to be self-contained where possible, only using external sites for references. and extra info. I'll remove my vote if you can go into as much detail as the answer by pjoters below.

Comment: I've added edits to the question. Please have a look @EngineerDollery.

Comment: Please let me know if anything else needs to be added.

Comment: A copy of the errors may help

Comment: Error was part of the steps. I've separated it to make it clear. Thanks for the feedback !

Comment: Okay, I've removed my close vote and given you an upvote due to this having become a pretty good question. Nice one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have reproduced your issue. The order of commands in this tutorial is wrong.

In this case you received this error due to lack of resource (samplecontroller)

```
$ ./sample-controller -kubeconfig=$HOME/.kube/config
E0430 12:55:05.089624  147744 reflector.go:125] k8s.io/sample-controller/pkg/generated/informers/externalversions/factory.go:117: Failed to list *v1alpha1.Foo: the server could not find the requested resource (get foos.samplecontroller.k8s.io)
^CF0430 12:55:05.643778  147744 main.go:74] Error running controller: failed to wait for caches to sync
goroutine 1 [running]:
k8s.io/klog.stacks(0xc0002feb00, 0xc000282200, 0x66, 0x1f5)
    /usr/local/google/home/user/go/src/k8s.io/klog/klog.go:840 +0xb1
k8s.io/klog.(*loggingT).output(0x2134040, 0xc000000003, 0xc0002e12d0, 0x20afafb, 0x7, 0x4a, 0x0)
    /usr/local/google/home/user/go/src/k8s.io/klog/klog.go:791 +0x303
k8s.io/klog.(*loggingT).printf(0x2134040, 0x3, 0x14720f2, 0x1c, 0xc0003c1f48, 0x1, 0x1)
    /usr/local/google/home/user/go/src/k8s.io/klog/klog.go:690 +0x14e
k8s.io/klog.Fatalf(...)
    /usr/local/google/home/user/go/src/k8s.io/klog/klog.go:1241
main.main()
    /usr/local/google/home/user/go/src/k8s.io/sample-controller/main.go:74 +0x3f5
```

You can verify that this api was not created

```
$ kubectl api-versions | grep sample
$ <emptyResult>
```

In the tutorial you have command to create **Custom Resource Definition**

```
$ kubectl create -f artifacts/examples/crd.yaml
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/foos.samplecontroller.k8s.io created
```

Now you can search this CRD, it will be on the list now.

```
$ kubectl api-versions | grep sample
samplecontroller.k8s.io/v1alpha1
```

Next step is to create Foo resource

```
$ kubectl create -f artifacts/examples/example-foo.yaml
foo.samplecontroller.k8s.io/example-foo created
```

Those commands will not create any objects yet.

```
user@user:~/go/src/k8s.io/sample-controller$ kubectl get all
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   XX.XXX.XXX.XX   <none>        443/TCP   14d
```

All resources will be created after you will run `./sample-controller -kubeconfig=$HOME/.kube/config`

```
user@user:~/go/src/k8s.io/sample-controller$ ./sample-controller -kubeconfig=$HOME/.kube/config
user@user:~/go/src/k8s.io/sample-controller$ kubectl get all
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/example-foo-6cbc69bf5d-8k59h   1/1     Running   0          43s

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.39.240.1   <none>        443/TCP   14d

NAME                          DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/example-foo   1         1         1            1           43s

NAME                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/example-foo-6cbc69bf5d   1         1         1       43s
```

**Correct order:**

```
$ go get k8s.io/sample-controller
$ cd $GOPATH/src/k8s.io/sample-controller
$ go build -o sample-controller .
$ kubectl create -f artifacts/examples/crd.yaml
$ kubectl create -f artifacts/examples/example-foo.yaml
$ ./sample-controller -kubeconfig=$HOME/.kube/config
$ kubectl get deployments
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @PjoterS ! I followed your steps and was able to replicate your results.

Comment: By the way, how to change something to trigger the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run those two commands from readme?

```
# create a CustomResourceDefinition
kubectl create -f artifacts/examples/crd.yaml

# create a custom resource of type Foo
kubectl create -f artifacts/examples/example-foo.yaml
```

Comment: I did not run the two commands, since the README instructs us to run the two commands after setting up the controller.