# how to run sample controller kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to run the Kubernetes sample controller example by following the link https://github.com/kubernetes/sample-controller. I have the repo set up on an Ubuntu 18.04 system and was able to build the sample-controller package. However, when I try to run the go package, I am getting some errors and am unable to debug the issue. Can someone please help me with this?

Here are the steps that I followed which were given in 
[Running Kubernetes Sample Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55875514/running-kubernetes-sample-controller)

could not achieve the same result but ended up having error after running first four commands
if any one could help me [this was the error which i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3WkM.png)

Comment: Are you running your cluster on GKE?

Answer (score 0):

Your kubeconfig is not located in `~/.kube/config` path. Set `--kubeconfig=<path>` flag along with kubectl command.

Comment: which path should i add it? i have no idea

Comment: @sriramsharathg set the path of your `kubeconfig`

Comment: in my cloud shell there is not file called .kube/config

Comment: i was able to figure out that adding the path thanks but now the error msg changed when i  executed this command `./sample-controller -kubeconfig=$HOME/.kube/config`

Comment: @sriramsharathg What's the error you're getting now?

Comment: i have updated the error image in the question @harik